Standards for Total Harmonic Distortion in Communication Systems
If I have a demodulated waveform obtained from an AM envelope detector and want to measure distortion using Total Harmonic Distortion (THD), is there a relevant standard for this? I found IEEE 519, but it primarily addresses the design of electrical systems. Perhaps the focus should be on determining the lowest level of harmonic distortion below which the human ear cannot perceive audio distortion?
The original message signal is a sine wave, and distortion with respect to the original message signal needs to be measured.

How would you be able to measure distortion in the received signal without comparing to the original (before modulation, transmission, reception, demodulation)?  Even if the human ear can detect distortion, we have no way of knowing whether that distortion was present in the original signal.

My bad, I should have mentioned in the question that the original message signal should be a sine wave, and distortion with respect to the original message signal will be measured. All these will be done in simulations.

@radastro added this comment content to your question. If you say "this should be part of the question", next time just go ahead and edit your question :)

THD is actually a poor measure of intelligibility for communication systems. The human ear is remarkably tolerant of high levels of harmonic distortion on sine waves, while quite sensitive to other forms of distortion (such as clipping) on peakier waveforms. Can you explain why you're pursuing this particular line of inquiry?

At first I was looking for ways to quantitatively determine distortions and came across THD as an indicator of speaker system and therefore I thought it would relate to the output waveform from a AM radio receiver to some extent.

@radastro but then you took a turn and were like "let's bring human perception into it", which makes sense if a human is what consumes the output of your system. But then, you chose a type of input no human cares about, a pure tone. So, you've built a bit of self-contradiction into it :) Maybe ask a new question that describes the use case of your AM demodulator in detail and asks what standards/approaches are feasible for assessing the quality of such a system. ("Quality" is meaningless without use case. A bad-quality thing for human eating might be a top-quality building material.)

And, as others have mentioned, this really sounds like a good class of questions to ask over on https://signals.stackexchange.com

I'm not sure whether you're asking whether there should be a standard for an accepted way to calculate THD,  whether you're looking for a number that THD should not exceed in audio systems by standard, or whether you're looking for some number that's more useful than THD

I am actually looking for a number that THD should not exceed in communication system by standard. Of course I am open to other measurements that are more useful. Reading back, I found relating the comms and audio systems through THD to be quite inappropriate, I will do more research on this.

@radastro I don't think you'll find anything covered by relevant standards that is based on AM. AM's dead, really. Broadcasting standards don't typically cover audio reproduction quality, so that's another reason you might not be overly successful going down that route. Maybe, as suggested, ask another question, giving a much larger picture of why you care about these things, what you're trying to do, and why you think these measures are relevant to you.

You should consider using a SINAD (signal in noise and distortion) measurement: -

Image from Electronics notes - What is SINAD: SINAD measurements
The technique measures noise and distortion and is an industry standard for radio receivers (AM and FM) as seen in this extract from the link below: -

SINAD specifications are found in many specifications for items like VHF radios, VHF / UHF walkie talkies, other radio communications system, particularly those using FM, but SINAD can also be used for AM and SSB.

The basic idea is that you inject a carrier modulated with a sine wave into the receiver and, on the receiver output, you measure total demodulated signal level alongside the signal level when the input sinewave is "notched" out.


The original message signal is a sine wave, and distortion with respect to the original message signal needs to be measured.

You don't need a measurement standard; you just need to literally apply the definition of THD, if your task is to find the THD. It's the simple relationship of the RMS of all harmonics to that of the fundamental in your output.

There are subtleties at play.
First, what is typically measured is THD+N, but THD is also possible with modern equipment. There are various broadcast standards, but typically it is enough to measure THD+N across a BW of 22-22kHz (the bandwidth of the measurement is very important). This page provides a good overview. You ought to state your measurement method (frequency, level and bandwidth).
What level of distortion is audible? These are deep waters. The type of distortion (odd or even harmonic) possibly plays a big part. A quick search will reveal much debate, but one of the more pragmatic, evidence based commentators offers his take here.
(As an aside, a better, but more unanswerable, question might be "what level and type of distortion is unpleasant?" - as some forms, notably that from tubes, are considered desirable by many listeners.)
As for standards, you might find some existing defined by individual broadcasters (BBC probably have or had some) but AFAIK there is not generally much on THD - everyone assumes you will be at 0.1% or better (or you have serious problems, this was fairly easy to achieve in 1970, and anyway pretty much all loudspeakers introduce about ten times as much distortion than this), and there you are. There is a great deal on levels, crest factor and so on, but not much on THD.

then again, if it's 2024 and you're designing an AM device, who would care about "hifi" level perceptive qualities? In all objective and subjective standards, compared to modern modulations using similar RF bandwidths, you'd sound "pretty bad", unless you're working at SNRs and bandwidths that are unreasonably high for anything practical. (Caveat: I'm not too familiar with analog wireless highest-end stage microphones; but for these, as you say, THD is not the measure you care about.)
